# typescript not recognizing the ajax find function

Tags: asp.net-ajax, typescript

I have a bit of a problem with my JS in an asp.net ajax application.
I have a lot of JS code that is in TypeScript files. It makes it much easier to code some someone like me with some limited JS experience.

However i also use the $find() method provided by MS ASP.NET ajax.
I do because i use a Telerik RadDock in my application and this is the only way i can manipulate the RadDocks in JS.

I change the titles, close and open them from JS.

Now i would like to have all the code in my TypeScript file, but unfortunately it does not recognize the function $find().

So every time i need to use the $find() function i create a new function and put it directly inside my aspx page, inside then i refer to it from my typescript files.

It was ok for one or two functions even if not ideal, but now it is becoming a real problem. There is a lot of code in the aspx file.

Can anyone advice me on how to fix this issue. Is there some way i can refer to the $find() method inside my TypeScript files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix is to add a declaration for the find method, like this:

```
declare var $find;
```

This lets you use it in any way you like, but won't give you auto-completion.

```
var result = $find();
```

In this example `result` will of type `any`.

If you want a bit more auto-completion, you can make the declaration more explicit - I don't know what the function does, but if it accepted a string and returned a number, you could add those to your declaration:

```
declare var $find: (input: string) => number;

var result = $find('Example');
```

Now the `result` variable will be of type `number` and if you don't pass the string, TypeScript will warn you.

Comment: Thanks That worked.
I could use some advice on how to get the auto-complete to work.
The use of the function is as follows:
$find("conrolname").set_title("titletname")
the find function returns an object which has a method set_title.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the DefinitelyTyped microsoft ajax library.  I prefer to install from nuget.  Then include this line in your javascript:

```
/// <reference path="/Scripts/typings/microsoft-ajax/microsoft.ajax.d.ts" />
```